# Youtube Search returning past live events

Tags: youtube-data-api

I'm using the new API URL to retrieve all the current live, but almost everyday the API returns past live events (not anymore) as if It was on live that time.

```
"snippet": {
"publishedAt": "2015-06-10T10:56:50.000Z",
"channelId": "UC6ozjPR4vgS0lGmj4FLC5QA",
"title": "Climatempo News AO VIVO -  Edição das 12h30",
"description": "Confira as últimas informações sobre as condições do tempo no Brasil e PARTICIPE!",
"thumbnails": {
"default": {
"url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/15QJYDg9YsI/default.jpg"
},
"medium": {
"url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/15QJYDg9YsI/mqdefault.jpg"
},
"high": {
"url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/15QJYDg9YsI/hqdefault.jpg"
}
},
"channelTitle": "climatempo",
"liveBroadcastContent": "live"
}
```

This video was live on 2015/06/10 but is returning as "live" today (2015/06/16).

I'm using this URL:
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId=xxx&eventType=live&type=video&key=xxx

Comment: Did you work this out, Adilson?

Comment: Not yet. Some old videos keep going as a live

Comment: I've run into this same problem myself. I think the data is being cached. I have a theory if you run a cronjob every now and then to get the data it might sort it out? If I confirm it does work I'll comment again.